# three.js:texture.needsUpdate doesn't work

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using image texture in three.js, and the image will change at run time. Codes like this.

```
var geom1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50);
var map1 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('0.png');
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: map1, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geom1, material1);
scene.add(mesh1);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
//then '0.png' changed
//...
//then following codes run, I need remove mesh1 and create a new mesh
scene.remove(mesh1);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
var geom2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50);
var map2 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('0.png');
var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: map2, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geom2, material2);
scene.add(mesh2)
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

but image texture used in mesh2 unchanged. It seems that I need use `needsUpdate`. I've used `map2.needsUpdate = true` after create `map2` and in the callback function when create map2, but it doesn't work.

I'm using `three.min.js r70` and `Firefox 36.0.1`.

Comment: As the textures have the same file name, could it be that the browser is caching the image? Just a thought.

Comment: I just tried your thought and you're right :), so how to solve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015489/how-to-prevent-browsers-from-caching-an-image

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact I'm using Python's flask, so I use javascript to add a random number.